# Nativescript project cannot run ng serve

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

If I try to run the following command, this happens:

```
ng serve
An unhandled exception occurred: No projects support the 'serve' target.
See "/tmp/ng-YKKFYj/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

in the same directory, where the angular.json, the package.json, src folder etc. is, see:

```
forest@forest:~/<project-path>$ ls -lsa
total 380
  4 drwxrwxr-x   8 forest forest   4096 dec   17 17:44 .
  4 drwxrwxr-x   7 forest forest   4096 dec   17 16:20 ..
  4 -rw-r--r--   1 forest forest    383 okt   26  1985 angular.json
  4 drwxrwxr-x   4 forest forest   4096 dec   12 14:16 App_Resources
  4 -rw-r--r--   1 forest forest    202 okt   26  1985 .editorconfig
  4 -rw-r--r--   1 forest forest    260 dec   17 15:43 .gitignore
  4 drwxrwxr-x   5 forest forest   4096 dec   17 14:02 hooks
  4 drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root     4096 dec   13 15:41 .idea
 12 -rw-r--r--   1 forest forest  11368 okt   26  1985 LICENSE
 20 drwxrwxr-x 567 forest forest  20480 dec   17 16:15 node_modules
  4 -rw-r--r--   1 forest forest     62 okt   26  1985 nsconfig.json
  4 -rw-rw-r--   1 forest forest   1315 dec   17 16:15 package.json
264 -rw-rw-r--   1 forest forest 267877 dec   17 16:15 package-lock.json
  4 drwxrwxr-x   3 forest forest   4096 dec   17 16:04 platforms
  4 drwxrwxr-x   4 forest forest   4096 dec   17 15:26 src
  4 -rw-r--r--   1 forest forest    670 dec   17 16:34 tsconfig.json
  4 -rw-r--r--   1 forest forest    126 okt   26  1985 tsconfig.tns.json
  4 -rw-r--r--   1 forest forest     38 okt   26  1985 tsfmt.json
  4 -rw-rw-r--   1 forest forest   3093 dec   17 17:44 tslint.json
  4 -rw-r--r--   1 forest forest   1575 dec   12 18:16 tslint_old.json
 16 -rw-rw-r--   1 forest forest  14103 dec   17 13:23 webpack.config.js
forest@forest:~/<project-path>$ ng serve
An unhandled exception occurred: No projects support the 'serve' target.                                                                                                                                           
See "/tmp/ng-dO1bgr/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Versions:

```
$ng --version:
Angular CLI: 8.3.19
Node: 12.3.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.803.19 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         8.2.2
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.3.19 (cli-only)
@ngtools/webpack             8.2.2
@schematics/angular          8.3.19 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.803.19 (cli-only)
rxjs                         6.5.3
typescript                   3.5.3
webpack                      4.27.1

$tns --version
6.2.2
```

The project can be build for Android though.

Comment: Did you create the project with schematics?

Comment: nope. https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/tns-template-drawer-navigation-ng.

Comment: so it seems, either I use a template, or I can have codesharing, not both? https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/creating-a-new-project

Comment: I think you should use schematics if you are not familiar with configuring Angular JSON for web, then copy code from template.

Comment: will do that. Figured much now :S Thanks. If you provide an answer, I'll accept it to close this in a QnA style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Schematics](https://docs.nativescript.org/code-sharing/creating-a-new-project) for code sharing project which does all the setup for Web and iOS / Android.

If you had created it from template, you might have to manually configure the project to support web.